# xampp 1.8.3 with PHP 5.5.15 - SID variable is undefined

Tags: php, xampp

Good day everyone,

I am running XAMPP 1.8.3 with PHP 5.5.15, and getting the following error when I point my browser (latest version of Chrome or FireFox) to index.php:

Notice: Undefined variable: SID in ...\index.php on line 1

First line of index.php looks as the following:

```
<?php if ( ! ( $SID) ) { session_start(); } ?>
```

This code used to work in previous versions of PHP (4.x.x).

After some online searching, I found that I need to set session.use_trans_sid to 1 instead of 0 (default). I did so, but the problem still persists.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Comment: PHP has the `SID` constant, it doesn't have a `$SID` variable. e.g try `if (!defined('SID'))`

Comment: So actually turns out that PHP syntax and rules changed quite a bit since I've developed the code (~2007-08), where xammp version was around 1.6.2, and the code that worked perfectly with PHP from back then, does not work with newer PHP versions any longer..

Comment: syntax hasn't changed too much. there's new additions. but the major (and long-overdue-should-never-have-been-necessary-in-the-first-place) change was killing off register_globals and magic_quotes.